# can't accept android licenses in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

hey' I'm new to flutter and I've tried to run it on visual studio code but when I tried to accept the android licenses I got this error: [image]

how can I accept the android licenses ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install the Android SDK

1. Click Tools in android-studio, SDK Manager.
2. In the SDK Platforms tab, select API 32.
3. In the SDK Tools tab, select Android SDK Command-line Tools(latest).
4. Click Apply and then OK to install the SDK.

Then install cmd-line tools
from `android-studio -> sdk-manager -> appearence and behaviour -> system settings -> android sdk -> Android SDK command line tools`

To install android-licenses
run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in your terminal

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Android Studio
2. SDK Manager
3. install android-licenses open cmd run **flutter doctor --android-licenses**
   then y enter y enter....

[image]